# Set default role for User Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

When new user register, if there is no role set, automatically to set default role (the lowest in hierarchy). I already created relation "Many to Many" via migrations and have three tables: **users**, **roles**, **user_roles**. So the main goal is to have at least one relation in `user_roles` for every user.

Below are listed both entities of Users and Roles
Users Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={"read"}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=100)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=100)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=100)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=100)
     */
    private $lastname;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Roles", inversedBy="users")
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $roles;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastname(): string
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname(string $lastname): self
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @param Roles $role
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addRole(Roles $role) : self
    {
        if(!$this->roles->contains($role)) {
            $this->roles[] = $role;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Roles $role
     * @return $this
     */
    public function deleteRole(Roles $role) : self
    {
        if($this->roles->contains($role)) {
            $this->roles->removeElement($role);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Roles Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\RolesRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={"read"}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RolesRepository::class)
 */
class Roles
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $sysName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSysName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->sysName;
    }

    public function setSysName(string $sysName): self
    {
        $this->sysName = $sysName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Traditionally your would just relate the role when you create the new user.  You would probably want some code to protect against the role from being deleted.  Another common approach is to just tweak User::getRoles to always return at least the default role.  Gotta to be a bit careful because your database does not quite match your user model but the rest of the app will not care.

Comment: What keeps you from adding a row into the relation table?

Comment: @NicoHaase that's my issue, how to do it, because now when i create new user, user has no relation with any role

Comment: Why not call `addRole` with the default role then?

Comment: Well, i've tried to do it in constructor, but to use **addRole** i need to pass object ot type Roles, which role is from table Roles. So basically i need to do some query in enity (which is bad practice) to get row with default role as object of type Roles

Comment: since you're apparently using api-platform, I presume you want a solution involving its mechanisms. for that purpose, have a look at this: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-persisters/#decorating-the-built-in-data-persisters , you may implement a data persister for your users, access the role repository in it and add the default role to users that don't have an id yet? disclaimer: I'm not particularly experienced with api-platform, so this is just an educated guess. (normally somewhere in your code there is a `->persist($user)` call before which you'd add the role)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have a relation for every default user<->role you could extend the `getRoles()` method by adding your default role.
I did something similar in one of my projects, it looked like this:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    if (count($this->getRole())) {
        foreach ($this->getRole() as $role) {
            $roles[] = $role->getRole();
        }
    } else {
        $roles = ['ROLE_USER'];
    }
    return $roles;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i want relation in table user_roles, i don't want to have user without role.